# Where is the location of the sqlite to be used in the monaca?

Tags: android, sqlite, monaca

Use the monaca, we are developing a mobile app. It is an application that uses the Sqlite using on Windows (Visual Studio).
While confirming the contents of the database, we would like to develop,
It is in trouble and do not know the bottom line of the created location of the database.

index.html

```
var db = window.openDatabase('Database', '1.0', 'SampleTable', 200000);
db.transaction(executeQuery, errorCB, successCB);
```

Where is 'Databese' file?
Do you understand?

Comment: by default location will be \<pkg-name>\data\data\database\....

Comment: I android place you know.
I want to know is where save on is the development environment windows.

Comment: Do you mean in AVD ?

Comment: visual Studio 's preview.